# Android: Random Images Linked to Certain Buttons?

Tags: java, android, image, button, random

Hi so I am currently messing about with android/Java code. The little program I am working on randomly selects and displays an image. This works perfectly but now what I want to do is link certain images to a button.

For example if a picture of a cat is displayed from the drawable then pressing the cat button would then pick the next random image and like wise if a image of a dog then the dog button would be the only correct input. If the wrong button was pressed the program would go to a game over screen.

Currently I have setup the code so on start a random image if shown and upon pressing a button no matter what the image is it will load the next. Here parts of the code I have used so far:

```
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Hold_Image);



        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndN = rand.nextInt(16)+ 1 ; 
        String imgName = "img" + rndN;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
        image.setImageResource(id); //creating the random selector
        cat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cat);
        dog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Dog);//button setup
                setButtonOnClickListeners();
    }


    private void setButtonOnClickListeners(){//button code

        cat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(???){//what should call the image number?    
                Random rand = new Random();
                int rndN = rand.nextInt(16)+ 1 ;  
                String imgName = "img" + rndN;
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName()); }//next random image upon correct button 
                Word.setImageResource(id);
                else{
//game over screen code(yet to write)
} 
            }
        });
```

### }

Update1: this is the code I have tried to get to work with Vlads  method. The problem I have is that the buttons aren't doing anything and the random image isn't working(only one image the same one each time shows)

```
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {
ImageView Word;
Button cat;
Button dog;
int max = 16;
int score = 0;
String imgName;
Random rand = new Random();
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Random rand = new Random();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
        Word = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.colour);
        cat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.theCat);
        dog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.theDog);   

            int rndN = rand.nextInt(16)+ 1 ; 
            String imgName = "cat" + rndN;
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
            if (id == 0) {
                imgName = "dog" + rndN;
                id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                Word.setImageResource(id);
            }
    }
    private void nextImage() {

        int rndN = rand.nextInt(16)+ 1 ; 
        String imgName = "cat" + rndN;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        if (id == 0) {
            imgName = "dog" + rndN;
            id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        }
        setButtonOnClickListeners();
      Word.setImageResource(id);
    }

    private void setButtonOnClickListeners(){
            cat= (Button) findViewById(R.id.theCat);
                cat.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View buttonClicked) {

                        if(imgName.startsWith("dog") && buttonClicked.getId() == R.id.theCat ||
                                imgName.startsWith("cat") && buttonClicked.getId() == R.id.theDog) {    
                            nextImage();
                        } else {
                            //game over screen code(yet to write)
                        } 

                    }

                });}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity1, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give the different types of images a different name, like all dog pictures dog1, dog2, ... and all cat pictures cat3, cat4, ... **Make sure the numbers stay the same as they were**. Then *define imgName as a class variable* and add this method: replace the line "String imgName = "img" + rndN;" with this:

```
private void nextImage() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rndN = rand.nextInt(16)+ 1 ; 
    String imgName = "dog" + rndN;
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    if (id == 0) {
        imgName = "cat" + rndN;
        id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    }
    image.setImageResource(id);
}
```

Now replace your onClick method with this one:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(imgName.startsWith("dog") && v.getId() == R.id.Dog ||
            imgName.startsWith("cat") && v.getId() == R.id.Cat) {    
        nextImage();
    } else {
        //game over screen code(yet to write)
    } 
}
```

And, obviously, also replace the part between "image = ..." and "cat = ..." with nextImage().

Comment: @Phil3992 I fixed my answer. The code should now work as you intended.

Comment: @Phil3992 One thing I see right away: You should only call setButtonOnClickListeners() once: in onCreate(). And as I already stated at the end of my answer: Replace everything inside onCreate *after* dog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.theDog); with nextImage();